# Git - Pushing changes from local branch to remote branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

While playing around with git in android studio, I think I have created a local branch called origin/makka. I have remote branch too named origin/makka.

When I executed the following git commands

makka@CC-UBUNTU3:~/project/Android$ **git branch**

makka
master
* origin/makka
temp

makka@CC-UBUNTU3:~/project/Android$ **git branch -av**

makka                215cdff Login Screen - working on Business Logic

master                1b4dfe2 First commit.

- origin/makka         d7293a8 Working on Signin

  temp                  851b8a5 Signin logic

  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master

  remotes/origin/makka 215cdff Login Screen - working on Business Logic

Now I would like to push all my changes in origin/makka to remotes/origin/makka. I dont know how to do it. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you hoping to replace the remote branch with your new one?

Comment: nope. Currently my changes are in local branch ( origin/makka). I want these changes to be updated in my remote branch (remotes/origin/makka). Basically push the recent changes in origin/makka -> remotes/origin/makka

Comment: @user5001783 do you really want to keep the local `makka` *and* the local `origin/makka` too ?

Answer (score 1):

> I think I have created a local branch called origin/makka.

It certainly looks like it.

> I have remote branch too named origin/makka.

Yes.  It's like being at a party where everyone is named Bob.  "Hey, Bob?"  Which one do you mean? :-)

This is a bad idea (having a local branch with a name that resembles a remote-tracking branch name) and your best bet is to rename that branch.  For instance, while on the local branch `origin/makka`, you can (at a command line prompt) do:

```
$ git branch -m anothername
```

and now you're on local branch `anothername` and `origin/makka` now clearly refers to the other one.

**None of this affects `git push` itself**, it's just a good idea to make things less confusing for *you*, not for git (which has its own rules for handling this).<sup>1</sup>

Once you've changed the local name, you can:

```
$ git push origin anothername:makka
```

for instance, to have your git tell `origin`'s git that you have some commits for them and you'd like them to put those commits on their `makka` which you'll then continue to call `origin/makka` on your side, without any confusion.

---

<sup>1</sup>Those rules are mostly spelled out in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  Part of the trick is that local branches are actually all named `refs/heads/branchname` and remote-tracking branches are all named `refs/remotes/remotename/branchname`.  Git normally strips off the `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` parts for you, but if you get yourself into this situation, git stops stripping some of the leading names, so as to be able to "tell one Bob from another" as it were.